# CSS3 not working on visual studio 2010

Tags: css

I have a solution built in Visual Studio 2008 and wish to add some new features of CSS3, hence I converted the solution to Visual Studio 2010.

Even after its successful conversion I am still not able to see the CSS3 features. I need to use border-radius property of CSS3.

Can I use it on the solution converted from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010?

Please help.

Comment: I don't use Visual Studio, but if you're using the IDE's rendering of html, it's most likely using IE's rendering engine and pre IE9 it won't render CSS3 (and VS 2010 came out before IE9 as well.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the visual studio doesn't auto-complete the code but the css3 conditions will work on any browser compatible (Chrome, FF, EI9, Opera, Safari),since it's all CSS and not compiled by Visual Studio.

Give it a try on one of those browsers (:

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is an update coming that will address that issue, but you should be able to view any CSS3 change when running the site.